# JPA Erro ao inserir um objeto produto que tem referencia a um objeto existente

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

estou com dúvida na anotação manytomany ,sei que a mesma serve para indicar pro branco que ele precisa criar uma tabela intermediadora e que por sua vez fica localizado encima de um elemento que será list

```
public class Produto {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private float preco;
private String nome;
private int qtd;
@ManyToMany
private List<Fornecedor> fornecedor;
@ManyToOne
```

private Categoria categoria;
A ideia é que eu possa criar muitos fornecedores nesta lista por exemplo; Produto achocolatado,fornecedor toddy e nescau,neste produto consegui adicionar dois do fornecedores nesta lista pensei na minha classe produtoRN(tipo um DAO ops trabalhando em pacotes)

```
public Produto inserir(Produto produto,List<Fornecedor> listaFornecedores ,Categoria categoria) { 
            listaFornecedores=new ArrayList<>();
            Conexao con = new Conexao();
            EntityManager em = con.getEntidade();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            for(Fornecedor fornecedor : listaFornecedores) {
                em.merge(fornecedor);
            }
            em.merge(categoria);
            em.persist(produto); 
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            em.close();
            return produto;
        }
```

Com este método receber uma lista e varrendo a mesma para conseguir usar o merge em todos objetos ja criados o problema que na hora de testar eu tenho que criar um novo objeto e persistir,Tentei utilizar o find para capturar os objetos existentes mas da erro,deve ser por possuir uma transation dentro de outra

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Conexao con = new Conexao();
    EntityManager em = con.getEntidade();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    ProdutoRN produtoRN =new ProdutoRN();
    Fornecedor forn = em.find(Fornecedor.class,1);
    List<Fornecedor>listaFornecedores=new ArrayList<>();
    listaFornecedores.add(forn);
    Categoria cat = em.find(Categoria.class,1);

    Produto produto = new Produto(200,"Achocolatado",20 ,listaFornecedores,cat);

    produtoRN.inserir(produto, listaFornecedores, cat);

    em.getTransaction().commit();           

em.close();
```

//instancia o produto

}
ERRO :

```
abr 24, 2018 7:50:13 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at sistemavendas.TesteProduto.main(TesteProduto.java:22) Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: sistemavendas.entidade.Compra at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:266)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analisando somente o *stacktrace* postado, percebe-se que o problema está no mapeamento da entidade `Compra`, conforme mostrado no trecho a seguir:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: sistemavendas.entidade.Compra
```

Seguindo a mensagem da `Exception` lançada, está faltando definir o atributo que receberá a *annotation* `@Id` na referida entidade.

Adicione a *annotation* no atributo que corresponde ao id da tabela na base de dados e esta `Exception` irá desaparecer.